# Computation of gradients

Tags: pytorch

I want to compute the gradient in the following scenario:
y = w_0x+w_1 and z = w_2x + (dy/dx)^2

```py
    w = torch.tensor([2.,1.,3.], requires_grad=True)
    x = torch.tensor([0.5], requires_grad=True)
    y = w[0]*x + w[1]
    y.backward()
    l = x.grad
    l.requires_grad=True
    w.grad.zero_()
    z = w[2]*x + l**2
    z.backward()
```

I expect [4, 0, 0.5] instead I get [0, 0, 0.5]. I know in this case I can replace l by w_0 but, l can be a complex function of x in which case it is important that I compute the gradients numerically instead of changing the expression for z. Please let me know what changes I need to do get the correct gradient w.r.t w

Answer (score 0):

You should print your gradients along the way, it would be easier this way.
I will comment out what's going on in code:

```
import torch

w = torch.tensor([2.0, 1.0, 3.0], requires_grad=True)
x = torch.tensor([0.5], requires_grad=True)
y = w[0] * x + w[1]
y.backward()
l = x.grad
l.requires_grad = True
print(w.grad) # [0.5000, 1.0000, 0.0000] as expected
w.grad.zero_()
print(w.grad) # [0., 0., 0.] as you cleared the gradient
z = w[2] * x + l ** 2
z.backward()
print(w.grad) # [0., 0., 0.5] - see below
```

Last `print(w.grad)` works like that because your are using last element of tensor and it's the only taking part in equation `z`, it's multiplied by `x` which is `0.5` hence gradient is `0.5`. You cleared the gradient before by issuing `w.grad_zero_()`. I can't see how could you get `[4., 0., 0.5]`. If you didn't clear the gradient, you would get: `tensor([0.5000, 1.0000, 0.5000])`, the first two being from the first `y` equation, the second one and the last from the `z` equation.